# var ball = document.getElementById("ball"); returns null object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got 3 files

file 1: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bounce.js"></script>
    <title>Bouncing ball</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='ball'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

file 2: bounce.js

```
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var nx = 0;
var ny = 0;
setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30);
function loop() {
    nx++;
    ny++;
    ball.style.left = nx;
    ball.style.top = ny;

}
```

file 3: style.css

```
#ball {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
```

i'm load the .css and the .js in the html file. 
Now i'm trying to get te div "ball"  and i want to do something with it. In this case, i want to let it bounce agains the borders of the browser. But the point is, i'm getting errors.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

The bonce.js can not get the elment ball. Why not? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The script is loading before the Html is finished. Move the script tag to after the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the element before it's loaded in the DOM. Do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Bouncing ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='ball'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bounce.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a good practice to include all your JavaScript at the bottom, so it doesn't block the page while downloading. And it will make sure you don't have any errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your code is executed before the DOM is ready. There is no element with this id at this time.

Put your code inside a onload callback :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    var nx = 0;
    var ny = 0;
    setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30);
    function loop() {
        nx++;
        ny++;
        ball.style.left = nx;
        ball.style.top = ny;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your script to the end of the page or wrap it in an onload event. You're executing it before the element has loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Bouncing ball</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='ball'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bounce.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```